# HD Tune 2.55 на больших дисках

Tags: железо, hdd, поиск-программ, проверка, диск

У программы [HD Tune](https://www.hdtune.com/download.html) есть две версии: бесплатная 2.55 и платная 4.60. В плане перечисленных на их сайте различий меня вполне устраивает бесплатная версия:

[image: скриншот различий]

Но есть момент, который меня в ней смущает - там явно происходит переполнение каких-то переменных. На следующем скриншоте видно ошибку в размере диска (2199 вместо 2794) и отрицательное значение в поле Position:

[image: скриншот порграммы]

Вот правильные свойства диска:

[image: скриншот свойств диска]

Понятно, что т. к. программа только читает данные, но ничего не пишет, диску она не навредит. **Но насколько можно доверять результату проверки (если делать полную)?** Допустим, объём проверенного я могу посмотреть в диспетчере задач (число прочитанных байт) и так понять, было ли проверено 2794 или 2199, но даже в таком случае я не могу быть уверен, что проверился именно весь диск, а не многократно проверилось начало. Может кто-то пользовался и в курсе, есть такая проблема или нет?

PS: А может вообще лучше воспользоваться какаой-то другой аналогичной программой?